# Would it make sense to close all questions tagged with now EOL distros tag to be closed?

Tags: discussion

I was going through the [Question Collection for 2014 Moderator Election Q&A](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/8325/2014-moderator-election-qa-question-collection), in which on of them was this:

- [Ask Ubuntu currently has the lowest Percent Answered of any Stack Exchange site. What do you feel caused this, and what is your personal opinion on whether - and how - to change that?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/8332/72576)

As a possible move, I wondered whether closing questions tagged with distibutions which are now past their life to be closed. I agree this is not at all a long term solution, but then we can't and we don't invest resources on those questions either.

Woudn't investing some resources in closing these question help improve these statistics?

If closing only new questions is the norm, wouldn't it mean that questions asked when the distribution was alive but now dead and not closed now, are open to answers?

Comment: **Only** new questions with EOL distros should be closed. Since the others were asked when the distro was alive...

Comment: @Alvar: Wouldn't this mean the questions tagged with EOL releases with no answers are open to answers?

Comment: Only new questions tagged EOL can be closed as EOL. Because the problem stated wasn't a problem caused of the software being out of date...

Comment: @Alvar: If such question still have no answer, does it make sense to keep them open?

Comment: yes it does because it was valid when it was asked. But why improve stats when this site is about solving questions, can be problem still be solved? then don't close it...

Comment: Really old questions that don't have good answers can sometimes be cool closed as not reproducible, but not EOL.

Comment: @Seth: Yes, tagging it as not reproducible too can be a solution, till it solves the actual problem(in hindsight).

Answer (score 2):

This can only be done if we had policy that ***ALL*** EOL release questions were off topic.

However, this is not the case.  Only new EOL release questions are considered "offtopic", so we can't arbitrarily close all questions tagged with an EOL release as "offtopic."  Some of those questions, as well, may be "How do I upgrade from [EOLRelease] to a supported version", and *those* are still on topic.

Comment: I didn't strictly mean **all** questions, as humans we could distinguish between an EOL-specific question to non-EOL specific question. Keeping that margin, others which are really not worth the manpower employed, should not be kept open.

Comment: @Jobin "Would it make sense to close all questions tagged with now EOL distros tag to be closed?" is your title.  "All Questions" applies to everything.  We don't have a reason to close older posts about EOL releases if the question was posted before the release EOL'd.  We *can* comment on those posts that they should upgrade, but with the policies that are currently in place we have no basis to close old questions as "offtopic" if they were posted before the EOL dates.